# How to make an ftp server that can send files over wifi

Tags: windows-7, ftp, android, wifi-transfer

I want to setup an ftp server on my PC to which my wifi router is connected. I want to be able to access files on my PC from my phone via the wifi. It would be even better if I could access my PC files on my phone as I would access files on an SD card. Is there a reliable and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a particular ftp server for that, you need a stable, externally-visible IP address on which a normal server (I suggest vsftp) can run. To make an IP address externally visible you normally have to enable that port on the router's firewall.

Note: DO NOT make non-SSL ftp (port 21) available on the open internet. You will get owned. Ideally, use ssh-ftp, part of the openssh suite, if your client can use that.

Note: You may find tools like OwnCloud, NextCloud or Synology Coud Station easier to set up safely: they give you the client-side tools and also introduce more secure configuration.